# Create a two-dimensional array and fill with a List of Char

Tags: java, arrays

I want to create a Matrix in Java but i want to fill the Cells with list of Chars.

For Example

```
         A        B          C
  A  <,m,D,m    >,D,f      <,s,>

  B  >,d,s,f    >,f,d,o   >,D,f 

  C  >,D,f     >,D,f      >,D,f
```

To create a two-dimensional Array i can use

```
int[][] multD = new int[5][]
```

I know the size of the matrix and want to use a 2 Dim-Array. How can i fill the cells with a list of Chars

Comment: You might want to add a `Java` tag to your question

Comment: Firstly, use an array of chars, not ints. Also you can assign multidimensional arrays like char[][] array = new char[5][] and then use array[0][0] = 'C' or something along those lines. Hope it helps.

Comment: But i have to fill the cells with a List of Chars . How does this work

Comment: use **List<Character>[][] matrix = new List[N][N];**

if you know the size of list in advance then you can use **char matrix[N][N][]**

Answer (score 1):

Java does not really have two-dimensional arrays. Instead, it has arrays of arrays

You should try the following:

```
List<Character>[][] matrix = new List[][] {
        new List[] {
                Arrays.asList('a', 'b', 'c'), // 0,0
                Arrays.asList('x', 'y', 'z') // 0,1
                // ...
        },
        new List[] {
                Arrays.asList('a', 'b', 'c'), // 1,0
                Arrays.asList('x', 'y', 'z') // 1,1
                // ...
        }
        // ...
};
```

---

You could also use `String` instead of `List`:

```
String[][] matrix = {
    { "abc", "xyz" /* ... */ },
    { "abc", "xyz" /* ... */ }
    // ...
};
System.out.println(matrix[0][0]); // prints "abc"
matrix[0][0] = "abcd";
System.out.println(matrix[0][0]); // now prints "abcd"
```

Comment: It says cannot create a generic array ??!

Comment: @user3118927 updated my answer again, you should probably use what I just posted instead.

Comment: Another Problem is that i just can access  the matrix by integer for exampe  matrix [0][0] = "Bla"  or matrix [1][2] = "Bla1" , but how can I access the matrix like matrix[A][A] = " BlA" ?

Comment: @user3118927 I updated my answer. Though this is as far as I'll go, this is your homework and it appears that you should do some reading ;)

Comment: I tell it again this is no homework i just want to know if this is possible or if i just have acces withe integer matrix[1][1] dont give me a bad -1

Comment: @user3118927 Information for the task at your hand, whether self-assigned or not, is readily available over the internet in many forms and languages. It may feel to you that I am being unkind, but providing you with specific solutions will not help you learn, and as it appears, it also isn't going to help you get through school.

Answer (score 0):

```
Cell[][] matrix;
```

where Cell is

```
class Cell{
   List<Character> chars;
}
```

Comment: Any chance of a bit more explanation?